# How to build an animating sine wave

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to accomplish an animating sine wave, and it technically works, but for some reason, my math is making the wave go up and down.

Here's my code

```js
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
let path = [];
let transform = 0;
let refCounter = 0;
let timeCounter = 0;

var fps = 60;

animate()

function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    dots.forEach((d, i) => {
      transform = (transform + Math.sin((i + refCounter) / 40));

      dots[i].style.transform = `translateY(${transform}px)`;
    })

    if (refCounter + 1 > dots.length - 1) {
      refCounter = 0;
    } else {
      refCounter = refCounter + 1;
    }

    timeCounter = timeCounter + 1;
  }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333ddd;
  transform: scale(1.5)
}

.dot {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .7s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
```

Any ideas where my math goes wrong?

PS! I know that having dom elements like that isn't a good way of building it. I'm just trying to get the math right first and then I will dive into canvas or SVG's

Comment: woow ! all these divs

Comment: You should append the dots programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are animating it using js and also css. They conflict with each other. Also you add transform value to the previous value which leads to an offset. Here is the corrected version of your code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaedVL?editors=0010

```
transform = (Math.sin((i + refCounter) / 40)) * 50;
```

50 is just a coefficient to make the change visible.

and in your css:

```
.dot {
    width: 1px; height: 1px;

    background-color: #fff;

    //transition: .7s ease;
}
```

As you see the transition is commented.

Also I changed the scale css directive above at first to simplify things, you can bring it back and remove the coefficient I have put in the js code.

Comment: Any ideas how one could have this way but have the starting and ending points on the level, axis?

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
<div id="canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;">
        <canvas id="sineCanvas" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    (function () {

if (typeof(Humble) == 'undefined') window.Humble = {};
Humble.Trig = {};
Humble.Trig.init = init;

var unit = 100,
    canvas, canvas2,context, context2,
    height, width, xAxis, yAxis,
    draw;

function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("sineCanvas");

    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 300;

    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = '18px sans-serif';
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.lineJoin = 'round';

    height = canvas.height;
    width = canvas.width;

    xAxis = Math.floor(height/2);
    yAxis = Math.floor(width/4);

    context.save();
    draw();
}

draw = function () {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = '#00f';
    context.fillStyle = '#fff';
    context.lineWidth = 2;

    context.beginPath();
    drawSine(draw.t);
    context.stroke();

    context.restore();

    draw.seconds = draw.seconds - .007;
    draw.t = draw.seconds*Math.PI;
    setTimeout(draw, 35);
};
draw.seconds = 0;
draw.t = 0;

function drawSine(t) {

    var x = t;
    var y = Math.sin(x);
    context.moveTo(yAxis, unit*y+xAxis);

    for (i = yAxis; i <= width; i += 10) {
        x = t+(-yAxis+i)/unit;
        y = Math.sin(x);
        context.lineTo(i, unit*y+xAxis);
    }
}
    Humble.Trig.init()

})();
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: A Simple copy/paste from here :https://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Lw41nwx7/ right? .. at least you did the effort to remove some code and the comments ...